Can't change keymap for "View Roll" in Blender 4.2
I am trying to remap "view roll" (originally Shift + Numpad 4) to (4).
To be clear, remap it to "4" in the main section of the keyboard, not in the numpad section.
I saved the preferences but it doesn't work. Reopened the shot, still doesn't work.
The original shortcut no longer works, but the new one doesn't either, although still newly listed in the keymap preferences.
I don't want to "emulate numpad" either (under Input in preferences) because it would override other shortcuts which I want to keep intact (as in 1,2,3 for vertex/edge/face select in edit mode, and numpad numbers for different camera angle toggles).
I have several keyboards connected to the computer, but unplugging some of them doesn't seem to resolve the issue.  Not sure that's what is causing the problem.
Tried resetting to preferences to factory settings, then trying all over again.  Same result.
Any thoughts greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Have you checked for conflicts? Number keys are typically used for layer switching
